# How to set small width to Gtk+3 Widget?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm using GTK+3 on MSYS2. I want to set width to 1 of GtkWidget but I can't it so please how to do it?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new("Hello, World!");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), label);

    // I want to set width to 1! 
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(label, 1, -1);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"but I can't it so please how to do it?"* ==> What behavior are you currently experiencing?

Comment: The program still keeps width of a label. I want to set width to 1 but `gtk_widget_set_size_request()` can't minimize.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for Gtk4:
"The size request of a widget is the smallest size a widget can accept while still functioning well and drawing itself correctly. However in some strange cases a widget may be allocated less than its requested size, and in many cases a widget may be allocated more space than it requested."

I recommend using the Layout-Manager for your problem.